# how to check if xml document has a certain list of attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

i am experimenting with C# and xml, i am trying to read a XML file i want to validate if  "NumberOfDays" , "NumberOfBooks", "NumberOfExam", "CurrentDate" are existing, if missing. i want to add them with there values.

i have the following xmldocument :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MySample>
  <Content>
    <add  key="NumberOfDays" value="31"  />
    <add  key="NumberOfBooks" value="20"  />
    <add  key="NumberOfExam" value="6"  />
    <add  key="CurrentDate" value="15 - Jul - 2011"  />
  </Content>
</MySample>
```

i am writing a sample application in c# using

**--------Edit--------**

thank you **AresAvatar** for your responce.

but if the value exists i would like to update its value i.e. if let's say

```
<add  key="NumberOfExam" value=""  />
```

i want to change the value to 6

Comment: Neel, the same method applies to setting.  I'll edit my answer to cover this (it's easier to see new questions like that if you leave a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of which nodes exist like this:

```
// Get a list of which nodes exist
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myXml);
List<string> existingNodes = new List<string>();
XmlNodeList bookNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/MySample/Content/add");
foreach (XmlNode nextNode in bookNodes)
{
    foreach (XmlAttribute nextAttr in nextNode.Attributes)
        existingNodes.Add(nextAttr.InnerText);
}
```

You can add missing nodes like this:

```
// Add nodes
XmlNode addRoot = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MySample/Content");
XmlElement addme = doc.CreateElement("add");
addme.SetAttribute("NumberOfDays", "31");
addRoot.AppendChild(addme);
```

You can set the value of existing nodes like this:

```
// Update a node
foreach (XmlNode nextNode in bookNodes)
{
    foreach (XmlAttribute nextAttr in nextNode.Attributes)
    {
        switch (nextAttr.Name)
        {
            case "NumberOfDays":
                ((XmlElement)nextNode).SetAttribute("value", "31");
                break;
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have control over the generated XML (if you make it yourself), avoid using this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MySample>
  <Content>
    <add  key="NumberOfDays" value="31"  />
    <add  key="NumberOfBooks" value="20"  />
    <add  key="NumberOfExam" value="6"  />
    <add  key="CurrentDate" value="15 - Jul - 2011"  />
  </Content>
</MySample>
```

It's much easier to use with that schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <MySample>
      <Content>
       <Adds>
        <NumberOfDays>31<NumberOfDays/>
        <NumberOfBooks>20<NumberOfBooks/>
        <NumberOfExam>6<NumberOfExam/>
        <CurrentDate>5 - Jul - 2011<CurrentDate/>
       </Adds>
      </Content>
    </MySample>
```

And then:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("YourXmlPath");
XmlNode firstNode = doc["MySample"];
if(firstNode != null)
{
    XmlNode secondNode = firstNode["Content"];
    if(secondNode != null)
    {
        XmlNode thirdNode = secondNode["Adds"];
        if(thirdNode != null)
        {
            if(thirdNode["NumberOfDays"] == null) //The "NumberOfDays" node does not exist, we create it.
            {
                XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement("NumberOfDays");
                newElement.InnerXml = 31;
                thirdNode.AppendChild(newElement);                    
            }
            //Do the same for the other nodes...
        }
    }
}
doc.Save("YourXmlPath");
```

Just remember to check for null on every node, or put the whole block into a try/catch.

And to save the XML once you did your changes.

XmlDocument.Load() function loads the XML in memory, so you can check for any node without making "blind loops".

Comment: This isn't really answering his question, it changes what he's doing.  He may have a reason to use the schema he did.

Comment: Yes, but if he's learning, he may as well not start by loading in memory what's already in memory =)